# Is it weird to say "lo" and "yea" nowadays?

Tags: word-usage

Is it weird nowadays to hear someone saying [yea](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/yea) or [lo](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lo) nowadays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's not weird to hear someone say these words, but they are mostly considered archaic and rarely heard in everyday speech today, except for perhaps a few expressions where they have survived, such as "lo and behold", or "yea or nay", or when someone is using them for effect perhaps.

Also these words appear in the Christian Bible (especially the King James version), and in Christian hymns - so many people will be familiar with hearing them in religious contexts.

Comment: So will many viewers of the series **Breaking Bad**.

Comment: @RonaldSole - yes! And anyone who has studied English literature

Comment: It is also  common to encounter the expression, "Lo, these many years," although I would regard this expression  as useful mainly for effect, not because it is  a customary way to refer to a long period of time.

Comment: @CharlesB.Cameron - really? Where?

Comment: https://ludwig.guru/s/lo+these+many+years https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9115357-lo-these-many-years https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lo

Comment: @CharlesB.Cameron - 'Common' for some value of 'common'. Every single source you linked to was American. If one encountered 'lo these many years' in a contemporary British text, one would perceive an intention to be quaint, picturesque, or (very) old-fashioned. Even in poetry you'd have to go back quite a long way to find 'lo' used naturally: _Far-called, our navies melt away;   On dune and headland sinks the fire: Lo, all our pomp of yesterday   Is one with Nineveh and Tyre!_

Comment: I agree. No one would regard this as customary usage, but as quaint or even archaic. So maybe it lives on more here in the U.S.A.

Comment: Even in the USA, I would say these are poetic, perhaps uncommon and quaint, although they definitely will be understood.

Answer (score 0):

Except in fixed idioms like "lo and behold", these words are archaic and not used except to create a deliberately quaint or biblical style.

Learners should not generally be using archaic words as if they were part of normal vocabulary.  That is you should not say "Lo! The supermarket is selling my favourite brand of coffee."

The same applies to "yea", however the closely related "yeah" is very much in common use.

Comment: Worth pointing out that *yea*, *yay* are pronounced differently from  *yeah*, the "h" in *yeah* maybe be silent but it gives a more slangy look to *yea/yay*.